# Возможно ли создать MotionEvent в пределах текущего Activity?

Tags: android, java

Хочу управлять телефоном с ПК. Создал интерфейс обмена данными от ПК к телефону по BlueTooth. Уперся в то, что не получается формировать тап по тачскрину. Точнее конкретную кнопку нажать могу

```
void simulateEventUp( View v, long x, long y )
{
    MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
                                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
                                        x, y, 0);
    v.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
}
```

а вот в любом месте экрана не получается.
Как можно имитировать тап в любом месте экрана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное использовать тот же метод у Activity:

```
void simulateEventUp( Activity yourActivity , long x, long y ) {
     MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
                                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
                                    x, y, 0);
     yourActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
```

}

Comment: Очень помогло!!!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на [обезьянку - MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) - вдруг можно приспособить как то?

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Не то что нужно, это для тестинга приложений, а мне нужно программно создать тап/сдвиг.